# Nodemailer not sending mails when deployed on Render

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

this is the code for my nodemailer.js file

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require("dotenv").config();

const smtpPass = process.env.SMTPPASS;
const PORT = process.env.port || 465;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    port: PORT,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'myEmail@gmail.com',
        pass: smtpPass
    }
});

module.exports = transporter;
```

below is the function to send email and a post route to handle schedule email. and below is the code i have written in my App.js file

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const nodemailer = require('./config/nodemailer');

// Function to send an email
function sendEmail(userEmail, callback) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'myEmail@gmail.com', 
    to: userEmail, 
    subject: 'Reminder',
    text: 'Your task is due for today'
  };

  try {
    nodemailer.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        callback(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent:', info.response);
        callback(null); // No error, email sent successfully
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    callback(error);
  }
}

app.post('/schedule-email', (req, res) => {
  // const emailDateTime = req.body.emailDateTime;
  const userEmail = req.user.username; // Retrieve the user's email from your authentication system

  // const emailDateTime = new Date('2023-09-30T14:30:00');
  const emailDateTimeStr = req.body.emailDateTime;
  const emailDateTime = new Date(emailDateTimeStr);

  const cronDateTime = `${emailDateTime.getSeconds()} ${emailDateTime.getMinutes()} ${emailDateTime.getHours()} ${emailDateTime.getDate()} ${emailDateTime.getMonth() + 1} * ${emailDateTime.getFullYear()}`;

  // Schedule the email to be sent at the specified time
  try {
    cron.schedule(cronDateTime, () => {
      sendEmail(userEmail, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error scheduling and sending email:', error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email scheduled and sent successfully.');
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error scheduling email:', error);
  }

  // Respond to the client with a redirect to the dashboard with a query parameter
  res.redirect("/Dashboard?message=EmailScheduled");
});
```

when i am working  on a local server (localhost), it is working, the email is being sent to the given email id. but when i have deployed my application to the render it is giving the alert email successfully sent, but it is not actually being sent. and no logs messages are being showed in the render logs section.

I want the email to be sent on render too but how?

Comment: See Nodemailer docs, [Using Gmail](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)